# Group by similar observations - rows

Tags: r

```
      Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4
row1   a    b     b1    c
row2   a    b     b2    c
row3   a    b     b3    c
row4   a    b     b4    c
```

The above mentioned are the scenario,

I would like to get an output like,

```
     col1 col2 col3  col4   col5  col6  col7
row1  a    b    b1    b2     b3    b4    c
```

How to reduce the no.of rows when we have all but one column has same values.

Comment: Try `unique(unlist(your_df))`

Comment: This might be a long-to-wide reshape problem.

Comment: I think the problem is a bit ambiguous still.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following code:

```
v<- t(as.matrix(sort(unique(unlist(df)))))
setNames(data.frame(v),paste0("col",seq_along(v)))
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), 
    Col2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "b"), 
    Col3 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"), class = "factor"), 
    Col4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("row1", 
"row2", "row3", "row4"))
```